# What was Natsume hiding in her closet in episode 11?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

In episode 11 of **Tokyo Ravens**, what was Natsume hiding in her closet?

Answer (score 3):

It was never shown in the whole series, but we can make some intelligent guesses. Here are the list of things Natsume hides:

1. She is a girl. No one except Harutora knows she is a girl.
2. She is the controller behind Hokuto.
3. She is obsessively in love with Harutora.

So based on these things, it could be

1. **Girl clothes, cosmetics, girly things, etc.**
2. **Clothes and kit that Hokuto uses.**
3. **A whole collection of things related to Harutora, maybe during his time with Hokuto. Pictures, memorabilia etc..**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Harutora, Touji and even Suzuka know she's a girl. So I don't think she's too worried about that sorta things like cosmetics or clothes being out at this point.

She also traipses around with that ribbon Harutora won and even has a tiger statuette on display, so I don't really think she's shy of the memorabilia all that much and I honestly don't think she's the sorta girl to build a shrine for her crush or something.

So taking an educated guess, I think it's her porn collection, seeing as Harutora's was subtly mentioned before this particular scene to be in his closet.